# Script to Enforce MFA failing to grab dataset from servers

Tags: function, powershell, multi-factor-authentication

```
function Enforce-MFA($exclude){
Connect-MsolService
$excludedUsers  = 'admin','admin2','admin3','admin4' + $exclude
$excluded = ($excludedUsers | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
$st = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
$st.RelyingParty = "*"
$st.State = "Enforced"
$sta = @($st)
$array = (Get-MsolUser | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -notmatch $excluded }).UserPrincipalName
ForEach ($user in $array)
{ 
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $sta
Write-Host "Complete"
}
}
```

The general function is to grab a list of objects, exclude certain objects, and Enforce MFA for the remaining objects. This script seemed to work without any issue last week, but this week, I'm getting no data from the Array variable. I was working on a lot of different changes and I'm thinking I may have messed something up in the process, but I'm just not seeing it. What did I mess up or what am I not seeing?

Comment: Can you show us how you call your function and what you enter for the `$exclude` parameter? Looks like that is where things go wrong. P.S. since the code uses regex, there is no need to specify all those admins. All users with the word `admin` in their displayname are captured if you do `@('admin') + $exclude`

Comment: The multiple admins are just fill ins for the actual admin usernames. I didn't want to make that public. That said, I actually removed "exclude" from the function entirely and it still doesn't seem to function. 

I'm calling the function through a while loop.

```
while(($var = Read-Host -Prompt " Enter the corresponding number: 1: Enforce  2: Enable 3: Disable  4: Exit ") -ne "end")
{
switch($var){

1 {Enforce-MFA}
2 {Enable-MFA}
3 {Disable-MFA}
4 {exit}
default{"Please choose either 1,2 ,3,or 4"}
}

}
```

Having some trouble formatting this code for some reason.

Comment: According to the prompt you give the Read-Host, ` -ne "end"` will never happen as the user is supposed to type `4` to exit..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `-Credential $cred` to the Connect-MsolService.
You should create that connection **first** and take it out of the function.

```
function Enforce-MFA {
    $excludeTheseUsers = 'admin', 'user1', 'user2'  # etc.
    # for using the regex `-notmatch` operator later, you need to combine the entries with the regex OR sign ('|'),
    # but you need to make sure to escape special characters some names may contain
    $excludes = ($excludeTheseUsers | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

    # create the StrongAuthenticationRequirement object just once, to use on all users
    $st = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationRequirement
    $st.RelyingParty = "*"
    $st.State = "Enabled"
    $sta = @($st)

    # get an array of UserPrincipalNames
    $array = (Get-MsolUser | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -notmatch $excludes }).UserPrincipalName
    foreach ($user in $array) {
        Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $user -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $sta
    }
    Write-Host "Enforcing MFA Complete"
}

# ask for credentials to make the connection
$cred = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter your credentials to connect to Azure Active Directory'
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
```

As for your loop, try something like this:

```
# enter an endless loop
while($true) {
    $var = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the corresponding number: 1: Enforce 2: Enable 3: Disable 4: Exit"
    switch($var){ 
        1 { Enforce-MFA } 
        2 { Enable-MFA } 
        3 { Disable-MFA } 
        4 { exit }
        default{ "Please choose either 1, 2 ,3 or 4" } 
    } 
}
```